# How to schedule a function to execute at a future time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application in which a user creates a record called a rooster with a boolean named "on" set to true. In rails console it looks like:

```
Rooster 
=> Rooster{:id integer, :user_id integer, :created_at datetime, :updated_at datetime, :on boolean}
```

Now, after some period of time (say, 10 hours) I need the app the automatically flip that boolean to "false" (the user doesn't do anything).

Pretty simple idea. So, how do I create a method in rails 3 that executes after some time period has elapsed?

Comment: My concern with in-Ruby solutions is whether the scheduled event will survive if the app dies or gets killed, or the machine reboots. OS-based solutions, like `at` and `cron` will survive but would require executing the system's commands, which would then need to trigger an app that could set the flag in the database.

Comment: interesting point. hadn't considered that.

Comment: It's one of those things we learn to think about after many years in enterprise situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With DelayedJob you can do something like

```
  def in_the_future
   # Some other code
  end
  handle_asynchronously :in_the_future, :run_at => Proc.new { 10.hours.from_now }
```

Very nice? :) I suggest you read the documentation as linked by jared

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look into either [DelayedJob](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SimpleWorker, a cloud-based background processing / worker queue for Ruby apps.

Designed to offload front-end tasks (sending emails, posting to twitter), running scheduled jobs, or scaling out a bunch of parallel jobs (web crawling, ruby hadoop, etc.). Great for just this type of use.

The jobs run in the cloud, so you not only offload tasks from your app servers you also gain reliability of running on top cloud infrastructure (the service runs on AWS using persistence data stores and message queues).

(Disclosure: I work for the company.)