# Perform a task in 15 minutes from now in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task, jobs

I'm creating a Rails application that let users book tickets for an event.

Once the user selects the ticket he wants to buy, he has 15 minutes to complete the checkout, otherwise the ticket will be released and can be booked by someone else.

How can I "block" the ticket for 15 minutes and make it available again after 15 minutes?

Comment: You can use delayed_job to run a task after 15 minutes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494369/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-execute-at-a-future-time

Answer (score 7):

Have a status field in your ticket model(or whatever model you are using) and mark it as partially_booked when user selects it.

If you are using delayed jobs,

```
handle_asynchronously :your_method_here, :run_at => Proc.new { 15.minutes.from_now }
```

If you are using sidekiq,

```
YourWorker.perform_in(15.minutes, ticket_id)
```

where 'your_method_here' or 'YourWorker' will contain the logic to check if booking was completed or not, and mark it as unassigned if it was not completed.

Comment: How to retrieve and show the remaining time on the page?

Comment: In sidekiq you will have to store the job_id somewhere, then you fetch job using job=Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job(job_id) and then job.at will return the time at which job is supposed to run.

Comment: btw, what are you using for background jobs.

Comment: Nothing Rohan. What should I use?

Comment: Perfect. Use Sidekiq, without a doubt. I have seen multiple startups eventually move to sidekiq if they had started with ActiveJob or DelayedJob initially. Performance and Scalability is way better, mainly because it uses redis cache for storing cache and not your database(like DelayedJob) and uses worker thread pools and queueing. You will find dozens of more articles making detailed comparison online, but conclusion is almost always sidekiq.

Comment: *uses redis cache for storing jobs

Comment: DelayedJob is great for starting working with background jobs because it works with already working ActiveRecord. Sidekiq is great! but you should install `Redis` as key value storage.

Answer (score 5):

`ActiveJob` helps doing jobs in the background. Using `ActiveJob` you can generate jobs for your delayed operations and enqueue them for later execution. You can add a boolean field to your model like `reserved` and make it true when the user first reserves it and run a background job so that if in 15 minutes later user won't complete the purchase, set it back to false:

```
TicketJob.set(wait_until: 15.minutes.from_now).perform_later(@ticket)
```

Active Job is a framework for declaring jobs and making them run on a variety of queuing backends. For setting up a backend for `ActiveJob`, take a look at [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). It is simple and good enough.

Comment: What's the difference between ActiveJob (built-in in Rails) and DelayedJob/Sidekiq/Resque?

Comment: `ActiveJob` is a standard wrapper around job processing backends like DelayedJob, Resque or sidekiq so that you can talk to all of them, the same way. For example you can change the backend from Resque to Sidekiq anytime without changing Job classes.

Comment: If you want to show remaining time for completing a purchase, you can create a `Reservation` model [like this](https://image.ibb.co/dQvPgQ/Screen_Shot_1396_02_24_at_12_26_27.png) and get the difference between current time and reservation created_at time.