# undefined method `handle_asynchronously'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I followed this article([How to schedule a function to execute at a future time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494369/how-to-schedule-a-function-to-execute-at-a-future-time)) to create schedule a method execution every couple of minutes.
 I added the bellow code after my update method in the model controller.

```
 handle_asynchronously :update_delay, :run_at => Proc.new { 1.minutes.from_now }
```

When i refresh the page i get this error

```
undefined method `handle_asynchronously'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your linked post says

> With DelayedJob you can do something like

So the method `handle_asynchronously` is probably a helper served by [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). You should **install the gem**

```
#Gemfile
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Run

```
bundle install
```

and

```
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Hi Pavan the error disappeared  but the function is not working as suppose to

Comment: @CharalambosPouroutides Did the job run or not?

Comment: No it didnt. I added my function in the controller in the private section

Comment: ''def update_delay
      require 'net/http'
      require 'json'
      url = ("https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube/status")
      uri = URI(url)
      response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
      @data_hash= JSON.parse(response)
      @data_hash.map{ |item| Delay.create(line: item['name'], description: item['lineStatuses'][0]['statusSeverityDescription'])} 
    end
    handle_asynchronously :update_delay, :run_at => Proc.new { 1.minutes.from_now }''

Comment: @CharalambosPouroutides Can you remove the private and check